# Not able to start docker container with shell script

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-java

This is the start.sh script i am using:

```
#!/bin/bash

touch app.log
HEAP_SIZE="-Xms1G -Xmx2G"
GC_ARGS="-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"
ARGS="$HEAP_SIZE $GC_ARGS"
echo $ARGS
echo $PWD

nohup java $ARGS -jar app.jar > app.log 2>&1 &

chmod a+r app.log
```

and Dockerfile

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:latest
WORKDIR /app/app-1
COPY ./ ./

CMD ["./start.sh"]
```

When i replace the start.sh in CMD with java -jar app.jar then it starts the container but with start.sh it immediately exists and i don't see any error either and i checked start.sh has execute permissions so not able to figure out the issue, any help ?

After further debugging found issue is with & in shell script command, so container is getting started but it exits immediately, but still don't know the exact reason of why it is happening with &.

UPDATED - 29-Apr-2020
I am able to start the app inside container by removing nohup and & (at the end). But with stdout and stderr are redirected "> app.log 2> &1" then it does not show 
logs when i run  "docker run -it ..." i.e. it is not redirecting logs docker container's stdout.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing nohup in the script.

Comment: well nohup is not a problem here, removing & works but not yet sure why.

Comment: There has to be an active process to keep the container alive, because of nohup and the & at the end the java process will go in background. Hence docker doesn't know which is an active process and assumes the container has finished its task and exits.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute the line `#!/bin/bash` for `#!/bin/sh`.
As it seems, the Docker Image `adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:latest` comes with `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/bash`.